# Make Webdrivers's Firefox Driver run in the background

Tags: integration-testing, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Hei

Is there a way to make Webdriver Firefox driver to run in the background?

We have a monitoring application which at regular intervals polls miscellaneous systems on different servers to check if they are running and responding as they should. To archive this we have made a small set of Selenium Webdriver tests.

We will have the application displaying on a big monitor in the maintainance departement, but it will look strange if Firefox is suddently popping up once in a while, is there a way to make it not run in a active window? Alternativly, is there a way for me to manipulate the browser size? Is there a way for me to determine where on the screen it should start (then I could make it start for example in the bottom right corner)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's triggering your Selenium/Webdriver tests?

I've set up Hudson as a Windows service before and the tests would run under the SYSTEM account instead of the currently logged in user account, so you wouldn't see the tests running.

I think the most straightforward way of doing this though is to set up a small Selenium grid (http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2), and have those tests run remotely on another machine. They can still be triggered from your wherever the monitoring app is running; the only change will be where the tests run.

Comment: sorry late reaply, this slipped my attention by accident.

good suggestions both. I especially like the idea of setting up the monitoring ap as a service and make it run under an other user, didnt know it wouldnt show up then, but when I think about it makes sense.

Comment: For this specific issue we ended up having two displays on the machine we use - one flat screen hanging on the wall and a regular PC screen on the computer in the room behind. I figured out how to make sure Firefox always opened and runs the test on the PC screen - I have made an own profile which Seleiumn use, and if you start "firefox.exe -P" from console, select that own defined profile and start it on the display you use, it will remember that and always open on that screen. That solved our case.